# select box change event of jquery working fine on localhost but not in LAN

Tags: jquery

I have four select boxes in jquery all working very good in localhost and in LAN three select boxes working fine but only one not working with jquery change event. I have tested script on firefox and chrome at localhost and on firefox in LAN

```
        $('#add_sub_dept_1').change(function(){
            $('#select_teacher_id').text(selectstring);
                dept = $('#add_sub_dept_1 :selected').text();

                var flag = "flag";
                if(dept != selectstring)
                {   var sub_html = "";
                    $('#display_teacher_box').html("");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: ({dept:dept,flag:flag}),
                        url : 'Scripts/display_sub_teach.php',
                        success:function(data){
                            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                              $.each(obj, function(key, value){

                                  sub_html += '<li style= "height:5px; font-size:15px; border:none; border-bottom:solid 1px gray;">' +    value.sub_name + '  -  '+value.teacher_id+'</li>';
                            });

                            $('#display_teacher_box').append(sub_html);
                        }
                    });  

                    var html = '<option>---select---</option>';
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: ({dept:dept}),
                        url : 'Scripts/fetchteachers.php',
                        success:function(data){
                            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                              $.each(obj, function(key, value){

                                  html += '<option>' +    value.name + '</option>';
                            });

                            $('#select_teacher_id').append(html);
                        }
                    });
                }
        });
```

Comment: what error you are getting in your browser console? Is their an jQuery `error`?

Comment: Hi again :) There data need to load into web page but nothing displaying just blank but it is working correct on localhost

Comment: Do F12 in browser and check in console. May be problem with jQuery path in localhost and live.

Comment: This is error but it pointing on jquery main script not my script=> Syntax error:Invalid object Identifier

Comment: Have get that error in localhost? and what error you are getting?

Comment: No not in localhost. All fine in localhost. This error is at client side actually i am using virtual machine kali linux for client and browser at kali is Iceweasel

Comment: I think you should check all jquery included linkes. i think problem with relative path or like that type of problem.

Comment: yes, it was thank you

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This may occurs due to some jQuery `path` related problem

You have to check included jQuery `path`. That may causes issue like workingin `localhost` and not working in `LAN`.